# What is the fastest and most concise/correct way to implement this model class backed by values in a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, big-o

I solved this problem using a graph, but unfortunately now I'm stuck with having to use a 2d array and I have questions about the best way to go about this:

```
public class Data {

  int[][] structure;

  public data(int x, int y){
    structure = new int[x][y]
  }

  public <<TBD>> generateRandom() {
     // This is what my question is about
  }

}
```

I have a controller/event handler class:

```
public class Handler implements EventHandler {

  @Override
  public void onEvent(Event<T> e) {
    this.dataInstance.generateRandom();

    // ... other stuff
  }
}
```

Here is what each method will do:

- Data.generateRandom() will generate a random value at a random location in the 2d int array if there exists a value in the structure that in not initialized or a value exists that is equal to zero
- *If* there is no available spot in the structure, the structure's state is final (i.e. in the literal sense, not the Java declaration)

This is what I'm wondering:

What is the most efficient way to check if the board is full?  Using a graph, I was able to check if the board was full on O(1) and get an available yet also random location on worst-case O(n^2 - 1), best case O(1). Obviously now with an array improving n^2 is tough, so I'm just now focusing on execution speed and LOC. Would the fastest way to do it now to check the entire 2d array using streams like:

```
Arrays.stream(board).flatMapToInt(tile -> tile.getX()).map(x -> x > 0).count() > board.getWidth() * board.getHeight()
```

Comment: Even mutating the already-selected elements, if you don't use some auxiliary data structure, deterministically finding a truly random available element requires searching the whole array of over a million elements; twice if you're allowed only constant storage. That's a bottleneck. Are you willing to spend a significant part of a second? Because that's what it will take. Niceties of how you structure the code come after you've figured out how to solve the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You can definitely use a parallel stream to safely perform read only operations on the array. You can also do an anyMatch call since you are only caring (for the `isFull` check) if there exists any one space that hasn't been initialized. That could look like this:

```
Arrays.stream(structure)
      .parallel()
      .anyMatch(i -> i == 0)
```

However, that is still an n^2 solution. What you could do, though, is keep a counter of the number of spaces possible that you decrement when you initialize a space for the first time. Then the `isFull` check would always be constant time (you're just comparing an int to 0).

```
public class Data {

    private int numUninitialized;
    private int[][] structure;

    public Data(int x, int y) {
        if (x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can't create a Data object with an argument that isn't a positive integer.");
        }
        structure = new int[x][y];
        int numUninitialized = x * y;
    }

    public void generateRandom() {
        if (isFull()) {
            // do whatever you want when the array is full
        } else {
            // Calculate the random space you want to set a value for
            int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(structure.length);
            int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(structure[0].length);
            if (structure[x][y] == 0) {
                // A new, uninitialized space
                numUninitialized--;
            }
            // Populate the space with a random value
            structure[x][y] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return 0 == numUninitialized;
    }
}
```

Now, this is with my understanding that each time you call `generateRandom` you take a random space (including ones already initialized). If you are supposed to ONLY choose a random uninitialized space each time it's called, then you'd do best to hold an auxiliary data structure of all the possible grid locations so that you can easily find the next random open space and to tell if the structure is full.

(2) What notification method is appropriate for letting other classes know the array is now immutable? It's kind of hard to say as it depends on the use case and the architecture of the rest of the system this is being used in. If this is an MVC application with a heavy use of notifications between the data model and a controller, then an observer/observable pattern makes a lot of sense. But if your application doesn't use that anywhere else, then perhaps just having the classes that care check the `isFull` method would make more sense.

(3) Java is efficient at creating and freeing short lived objects. However, since the arrays can be quite large I'd say that allocating a new array object (and copying the data) over each time you alter the array seems ... inefficient at best. Java has the ability to do some functional types of programming (especially with the inclusion of lambdas in Java 8) but only using immutable objects and a purely functional style is kind of like the round hole to Java's square peg.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This is actually a CS assignment  I'm a bit upset that I have to rewrite to make compatible with other students after I broke the standard interface which required 2d arrays/n^2. My prof is a bit old school (i.e. <java 7) and joked about all of the new-fangled JDK8 features so I'm going to make this with as many streams and lambdas as possible;)